# What does a wireless card need to work as an Access Point

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, routing, hardware-rec

What specifications does a wireless network card need to have to be able to work in a router?

I heard that it is not possible to use a normal wireless card to handle more than one connection, so what makes the difference between a normal card and those that are able?

To clarify: I have my own box (the router) running gentoo, iptables and dhcp but only with ethernet and want to upgrade it to wireless.

I am not looking for a specific item or card to buy, but for the name of the *"can handle more than one connection at once"*-option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you mean by not able to handle more then one connection?

Most wireless equipment cannot listen/transmit on multiple channels at once, but this isn't required for an access point.

If you are looking to add a wireless device to interface to a router, then I am assuming you want to setup the router as a wireless AP.  So you need a wireless card that can act as an access point.  Lots of devices can do this.

You will need a wireless card that is naively supported, and not operating through NDISWrapper.

Since you are using Gento, take a look at this page in the Gentoo Wiki, it includes many compatible devices in addition to details on how to set this up, read the hardware compatibility for details about what is known to work and not work.  http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Wireless/Access_point